# Как добавить валидацию на Null на уровне конструктора?

Tags: c#, конструктор, .net-5

```
abstract class Base
{
    public Base(int i)
    {
        
    }
}

class Foo : Base
{
    public Foo(string s) : base(s.Length)
    {
        
    }
    
}
```

С учётом того, что Base класс может быть в другой библиотеке, к изменению которой доступа нет. Пробовал null coalescing оператор, но ругается, что левая часть выражения должна быть ссылочного или nullable типа:

```
public Foo(string s) : base(s.Length ?? 0)
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам.

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимании "валидация на Null"? Что должно произойти, если s == null ?

Comment: `base(s?.Length ?? 0)` - так пробовали?

Comment: @aepot netcore 5.0

Comment: Этот вариант работает, да. Спасибо)

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ ниже, он тоже по сути правильный.

Comment: @aepot Но ваша конструкция правильнее/красивее. Забыл я что так тоже можно )

Comment: Я внес в ответ этот кусочек кода.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну можно тернарный оператор использовать:

```
base(s == null ? 0 : s.Length)
```

Или так тоже можно

```
base(s?.Length ?? 0)
```

Хотя не очень понятно, какое вы поведение всё же хотите в случае `null`, но предположим, что такое.

Валидация обычно предполагает, что если аргумент неподходящий, то нужно бросать исключение или ещё как-то сигнализировать об ошибке, а тут вы пытаетесь приспособиться к ситуации. А может не надо этого делать?

Comment: Изначально хотел передать в базовый конструктор длину в 0. А логгирование или исключение прописать позже

Comment: @thepotion33 Но в целом эти классы смогут нормально что-то делать, если туда `null` придёт (если починить ошибку с `Length`)? Если в этом есть какой-то смысл, то ок, а если они всё-равно работать нормально не будут, то кидайте исключение, не стесняйтесь.

Comment: Это больше как учебный пример реализации самого валидатора без дальнейшего расширения классов. Но за совет спасибо, буду знать, когда что делать)

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно не подавить ошибку, а бросить исключение. Проблема в том, что вы не можете это сделать «внутри» тела конструктора, т. к. до начала работы тела конструктора вам нужно вызвать базовый конструктор, а проверка должна быть *до вызова базового конструктора*, то есть на этапе вычисления аргументов для базового конструктора.

Самый простой код, который это делает, видимо, такой:

```
public Foo(string s) : base((s ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s))).Length)
{
}
```

Это выглядит нечитаемо (особенно если таких аргументов у вас много), поэтому, возможно, лучше вынести проверку в отдельную статическую функцию:

```
static string Checked(string s) => s ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

public Foo(string s) : base(Checked(s).Length)
{
}
```

Ну или если хочется в старом стиле, то

```
static string Checked(string s)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    return s;
}
```

---

Поскольку метод довольно общий, можно вынести его в отдельный helper и применять:

```
static class ValidationHelper
{
    public static T EnsureNotNull(T? t, string name) where T : class =>
        t ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
}
```

и пользоваться как-то так:

```
using static ValidationHelper;

...

public Foo(string s) : base(EnsureNotNull(s, nameof(s)).Length)
{
}
```

Когда в будущем в C# [реализуют-таки `[CallerArgumentExpression]`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/287), можно будет писать изящнее:

```
static class ValidationHelper
{
    public static T EnsureNotNull(
        T? t,
        [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(t))] string name = null)
            where T : class =>
        t ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
}

...

using static ValidationHelper;

...

public Foo(string s) : base(EnsureNotNull(s).Length)
{
}
```